# How to Modify MongoDB Object Located in an Array that is Nested in Another Array?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, aggregation-framework, nestjs

I have the problem where I need to modify a specific field of a object that is located in a array, but I would need to filter out the object within another array to get that specific object.  For example, lets say I have the following document:

```js
{
 _id: '1'
 name: 'Plan',
 builds: [
   {
     _id: '11'
     number: 20,
     type: 'Test Object 1',
     artifacts: [
      {
        link: 'helloworld.com',
        minioPath: 'test.zip'
        _id: '111'

      },
      {
        link: 'helloworld.com',
        minioPath: 'test15.zip',
        _id: '112'
      }
     ]
   },
   {
     _id: '12'
     number: 21,
     type: 'Test Object 2',
     artifacts: [
      {
        link: 'mongo.com',
        minioPath: 'test20.zip',
        _id: '211'
      },
      {
        link: 'mongo.com',
        minioPath: 'test25.zip',
        _id: '212'
      }
     ]
   }
 ]
}
```

What I would like to do is the following:

1. Filter out the specific `build` object from the `builds` array.
2. Filter out the specific `artifact` object from the `artifacts` array.
3. Update the `minioPath` field to desired value.

For this problem, I am using MongoDB in NestJS to build an aggregation pipeline. This is what I have so far:

```js
async getBuildItemArtifacts(id: string, buildItemId: string) {
    const buildPlanCondition = isMongoId(id)
      ? { _id: new Types.ObjectId(id) }
      : { key: id };

    const matchStage: PipelineStage.Match = { $match: buildPlanCondition };
    const filterBuildStage: PipelineStage[] = [
      {
        $project: {
          builds: {
            artifacts: {
              $filter: {
                input: '$artifacts',
                as: 'artifact',
                cond: {
                  $eq: [
                    '$$artifact._id',
                    new Types.ObjectId('111'),
                  ],
                },
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
    ];

    const {
      builds: [result],
    } = await this.builds
      .aggregate<Partial<Build>>([matchStage, ...filterBuildStage])
      .then(([doc]) => {
        if (_.isUndefined(doc) || _.isEmpty(doc?.builds)) {
          throw new ApiError(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, 'No data found');
        }
        return doc;
      });

    return result;
  }
```

So far, I'm able to filter out the specific `build` object, but I'm now sure how to go about filtering out the specific `artifact` object.  The aggregation pipeline got a little confusing, so any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: _"... modify a specific field of a object that is located in a array ..."_  Are you looking to update the document in the collection, or just output the result of an aggregation pipeline?

Comment: @rickhg12hs I am looking to update the document in the collection

Comment: @NathanBernardo does the code only doing get using aggregate?

Comment: Pretty sure `_id: _id: ObjectId('64011j746399dd1845357894')` is not the line you wanted.   Would you update your example doc?

Comment: @TobokSitanggang At the moment, yes.  It's only getting the specific `build` object from `builds` array.  Initially, I thought $filter would help filter out the desired `artifact`, and then use the $set command to update the `minioPath` field.  I'm also not sure if $project is necessary here when I could  use $set method and apply some filters to grab the desired `artifact` and update the field.

Comment: @rickhg12hs Just updated the example document.  I also made the ids simple for readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `update` is pretty easy using [`"arrayFilters"`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/).

```js
db.collection.update({
  _id: "1"
},
{
  "$set": {
    "builds.$[buildElem].artifacts.$[artElem].minioPath": "test42.zip"
  }
},
{
  "arrayFilters": [
    {"buildElem._id": "11"},
    {"artElem._id": "111"}
  ]
})
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/UWuEwjmns8L).

Comment: This worked!  Wow, I am in jubilation.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

*filtering out the specific artifact object*

to filter out of them

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      _id: "64011d1c2839dd1845354dfb"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "builds": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": {
            "$map": {
              "input": "$builds",
              "as": "build",
              "in": {
                "_id": "$$build._id",
                "artifacts": {
                  "$filter": {
                    "input": "$$build.artifacts",
                    "as": "artifact",
                    "cond": {
                      $eq: [
                        "$$artifact._id",
                        "64011d302839dd1845354e00",
                        
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "as": "build",
          "cond": {
            "$ne": [
              "$$build.artifacts",
              []
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      
    },
    
  },
  
])
```

[MONGO-PLAYGROUND](https://mongoplayground.net/p/covlPNQ13Mb)

here how to update

```
db.collection.update({
  "_id": "64011d1c2839dd1845354dfb",
  "builds._id": "64011d302839dd1845354dfe",
},
{
  $set: {
    "builds.$.artifacts.$[elem].minioPath": "mini mini"
  },
  
},
{
  "arrayFilters": [
    {
      "elem._id": "64011d302839dd1845354e00"
    }
  ]
})
```

[MONGO-PLAYGROUND](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OcgZ95UcEkW)

Comment: @NathanBernardo i did change on the ObjectId, but this should match with your requirments

Comment: Thanks!  This is pretty neat.  Would you happen to have an idea how how I could update the specific artifact? For example, the `minioPath` field?

Comment: sure, let my try